# Parse a Unix Command

Tags: bash, parsing, unix

I am looking to parse the return of the command `ll *.dat > output.txt`.  This produced a text file:

```
-rw-rw-rw-    1 root     root           16 Apr  8 12:15 01_entries.dat
-rw-rw-rw-    1 root     root           32 Apr 23 15:21 02_entries.dat
```

I then want to parse the these, so I see 9 tokens pair line:

`permissions`, `num of links value`, `user`, `group`, `size`, `month`, `day`, `time` and `filename`.

```
input1="output.txt"
while
        IFS='   ' read -r f1 f2 f3 f4 f5 f6 f7 f8 f9
do
        echo "$f1, $f2, $f3, $f4, $f5, $f6, $f7, $f8, $f9"
done < "$input1"
```

But this locks into an eternal loop - any suggestions on how I can get each line to parse correctly?

Comment: `input1="output.txt"` does not make sense, it should be `input1=$(cat output.txt)`.  But in fact you can just do `while ... do ... done < output.txt`

Comment: Your code is working for me but I don't think setting `IFS='    '` is necessary.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Instead of parsing the output of `ls -l` (which is pretty error-prone, locale-dependent and all), why not `find` a command that gives you the desired output directly?

(Yes, I know. Sorry for the bad pun.)

```
# -maxdepth 1: Maximum recursion depth (1 == current directory only).
# -type f: Files only (no directories).
# -name ...: Name pattern of files to list. Escape the \* so the shell does not.
# -printf ...: Format of the listing, printf() style:
#    %M: File permissions, symbolic view. Use %m for octal.
#    %n: Number of hard links to file.
#    %u: User name if present, or numeric ID. Use %U for numeric ID only.
#    %g: Group name if present, or numeric ID. Use %G for numeric ID only.
#    %s: File size in bytes. Use %b for 512-byte blocks, %k for 1k blocks.
#    %Tm: Last modification timestamp, month (01..12).
#    %Td: Last modification timestamp, day (01..31).
#    %TH: Last modification timestamp, hour (00..23). (Yanks use %TI and %Tp.)
#    %TM: Last modification timestamp, minute (00..59).
#    %p: Filename.
find . -maxdepth 1 -type f -name \*.dat -printf "%M,%n,%u,%g,%s,%Tm,%Td,%TH:%TM,%p\n"
```

Check `man find` for more options to `-printf`, and `find` in general. (Be especially careful with the date / time fields, since you aren't querying the year here...)

---

Gratuitious time data quiz question: What is the range of values for `%Ts` (modification time, seconds)?

- 00..59? Wrong.
- 00..60? Wrong.
- 00..61? Correct.

If you don't know why, better read up on "[leap seconds](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Leap_second)" if you want to write stable time-stamp parsing code. ;-)

Comment: This is an idea I had not thought about!  Thanks for this!

Answer (score 2):

Sounds like you're trying to produce a CSV file of some sort.

Probably better to do that the proper way (e.g. Python has a [great library](https://docs.python.org/2/library/csv.html) for this) for a variety of reasons: quoting, commas in filenames, spaces in filenames, important whitepace etc.

However a quick-and-dirty solution in bash might be:

```
ls -l *.dat | awk '{print $1", "$2", "$3", "$4", "$5", "$6", "$7", "$8", "$9}'
```

You could of course iterate over the parameters in awk properly, but then, err, it's not as quick and dirty...

Note also how this didn't use the alias `ll` in your script - it can mean different things to different users. Better to use the binary directly (`ls -l`).